# How to convert string formula in c#?

Tags: c#

How can I use this formula in c# ?

```
double Diameter = 160;

double Height = 118.2;

double pi = 3.1416
```

double Result =

[image]

Comment: See the class `System.Math`.

Comment: What did you try? What don't you understand? Are you asking how to multiply numbers?

Comment: Check the System.Math-class it has nearly everything you need. Otherwise you can look for libraries like MathUtils:
https://github.com/Artentus/MathUtils

Comment: Your formula looks like it may have a mistake, you have `sin^-1` but then only surround `2 * Height - 1` in parentheses. Assuming you have the original equations you may want to look into breaking that up into multiple steps, that is a really complicated equation to be doing in one pass. Also `Math.PI` has the correct value for pi has a double.

Comment: I agree with Guvante, this is too much to do in one result... it would be super noisy.  Breaking this into parts is the best approach.  It is important you know *what* the equation is doing.  Once you have that down, just use `System.Math` to do the exponents, trig and square roots.  Should be pretty easy stuff.  Also always use `Math.Pi` for pi.  Yours is lacking precision for a `double` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you **[read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** and pretty much code it up as written:

```
public static double ComputeResult( double diameter , double height )
{
  double result =   0.5
                  * (
                          ( (2.0*height) - diameter )
                        * Math.Sqrt( (height*diameter) - Math.Pow(height,2.0) )
                      +   (diameter/2.0)
                        * Math.Asin( 2.0*height -1.0 )
                        / diameter
                      + ( Math.PI * Math.Pow(diameter,2.0) )
                        / 2.0
                    ) ;
    return result ;
}
```

Though your formula seems to spit out `NaN` (not a number) quite a bit.

It'll be easier to check your computations if you refactor it to evaluate each intermediate computation individually and build up the result as you go along, much like you'd do if working on paper/blackboard/slide rule/calculator.

You've got essentially 3 multiplicative expressions that are computed, summed together and divided by 2, so you could break it up into at least 3 pieces (though I'd probably go further):

```
public static double ComputeResult( double diameter , double height )
{
  double t1 = ( (2.0*height) - diameter )
            * Math.Sqrt( (height*diameter) - Math.Pow(height,2.0) )
            ;
  double t2 = ( diameter / 2.0 )
            * Math.Asin(2.0*height-1.0)
            / diameter
            ;
  double t3 = ( Math.PI * Math.Pow(diameter,2.0) )
            / 2.0
            ;
  double result = 0.5 * ( t1 + t2 + t3 ) ;
  return result ;
}
```

Comment: result return NaN.What does this mean ?

Comment: Nan = Not A Number. Standard floating point error condition. Things like division by zero, taking the square root of a negative number, trying to get the inverse sine of a value x outside the domain -1 <= x  <= +1, etc. will generate `Nan`. And `NaN` propagates.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Operations_generating_NaN. As others have pointed out your formula seems to have some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `Math` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math(v=vs.110).aspx) class... methods such as POW and SQRT are available there.